# How to get shareable link of the uploaded file to Google drive using Google drive API v3 in Java

Tags: java, google-drive-api

All I wanted to do is:
1)Upload file to Google drive - done
2)Get shareable link of this uploaded file and set its permissions to "Anyone with the link can view" using **Google drive Java API v3**.

After file upload i tried doing `file.getWebViewLink()`; but the same is coming as null. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you checking the [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java) first and try modifying the code. There's a line there like `service.files().list()` which you can try to set to  `service.files().get().setFields("webViewLink");` to fetch the `webViewlink` property.

Comment: File file = service.files().get("YOUR_FILE_ID").setFields("webViewLink").execute();
file.getgetWebViewLink();

Answer (score 2):

To actually **enable link sharing** using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing):

```java
Permission permission = new Permission()
    .setType("anyone")
    .setRole("reader");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, permission)
//... see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing
```