# Google Drive API WebContentLink

Tags: google-drive-api

how can I view a file in the browser with php in version v3 of google drive api, the query does not return anything to me webcontentlink

Comment: Dont know about php implementation, but I did it in java as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140317/how-to-get-shareable-link-of-the-uploaded-file-to-google-drive-using-google-driv). Php implementation will be also somewhat similar.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is super old but i'll answer this anyway.

Google Drive Api V3 no longer returns all fields by default, so you have to request which fields you want to be returned in the 'fields' alternate parameters

so, by example

```
$file = $service->files->get( $id, array( "fields" => "id, webContentLink" ) );
```

google will now return the webContentLink

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working for **listFiles** like this: `$files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);`